# Can you use the results of a Power BI Report Server report as a data source in a C#, Python or PowerShell program?

Tags: python, c#, powershell, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

My question may be dumb, but I am completely new to Power BI, so please bear with me.

If I understand correctly, you can use the 'Analyze in Excel' option in order to create a sort of 'data link' between Power BI Data Server and Excel, which creates an Excel sheet where the data is always up do date. I want to use a similar thing but in C#, Python or PowerShell. Is it even possible? I searched the internet, but nothing interesting came up. Basically, I want to periodically export the data from a Power BI report and use it in a C#, Python or PowerShell program.

Answer (score 1):

"Analyse in Excel" is not availablable for onPrem Power BI Report Server. But if the Report is of type "paginated report" you can use the odata feed feeder go get the data of the report: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/access-dataset-odata